# AccessViolationException in .NET Core 5 with Advantage Data Provider

Tags: c#, .net-5, worker, advantage-database-server

I need to connect to Advantage Database for a Worker I'm working on.

I'm using the NuGet package **Advantage.Data.Provider** like so:

```
var conn = new AdsConnection("Data Source=\\Users\\[mypath];Initial Catalog=Test.add; User ID=adssys; Password=passw; ServerType=LOCAL");

if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    conn.Open();
}
return conn;
```

After adding lots of .dll in System32 to fix other errors, I'm now stuck in this one:

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.AccessViolationException Ocorreu
> uma exceção sem tratamento do tipo "System.AccessViolationException"
> em Advantage.Data.Provider.dll: 'Attempted to read or write protected
> memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

I can't get it to work. I've tried using others NuGets like AdoNetCore.AseClient and iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere, but they also cause errors.

If anyone could help me with this error or has a better solution to my problem, I would appreciate it.

I'm using VS Code and C#.

Comment: Did you install the dataprovider? (dataprovider.exe) is an actual executable you have to run once on your device

Comment: For ADS 8.1 it's like [here](https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=20&Release=10#:~:text=Advantage%20.NET%20Data%20Provider). But for the latest version I wouldn't know where to find it

Comment: Then we're able to 1) get a connection using `DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Advantage.Data.Provider").CreateConnection()`. 2) Set the connection string `conn.ConnectionString = "DATA SOURCE=C:\Ads\Databases\Example.add;ServerType=remote;USER ID=ADSSYS;PASSWORD=xxx;"` 3) `connection.Open()`

Comment: But I just think you didn't install the dataprovider exe

Comment: Downloaded and installed, but nothing changed. Tried using the code you just posted but gives this error "The specified invariant name 'Advantage.Data.Provider' wasn't found in the list of registered .NET Data Providers". I tried registering the AdsFactory, but it is not valid. But thanks @Pieterjan !

Comment: You also have to modify your `app.config`

Comment: Can you try updating the app.config? Ofc most likely you'll have to modify the version, and the PublicKeyToken, but I don't have a clue how to get this one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ended up working for me was:

First just like @Pieterjan said-

- Use the NuGet package `Advantage.Data.Provider` (Version 8.10.1.2)
- Install the .NET Data Provider corresponding to my DB version (https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=20&Release=16&Product=4&Platform=11)

Then-

- Get *ace32.dll*, *adsloc32.dll*, *axcws32.dll* and *adslocal.cfg* from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Advantage 10.10\ARC` and put it in an environment path location (like System32, but it would be recommended to create a new one just for this)
- Run the project with `dotnet run -r win-x86`

Apparently the NuGet package can only be run with x86, I think that was the main problem

Answer (score 0):

Install the Advantage Database Server dataprovider ([ADS 8.1 provider](https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=20&Release=10#:%7E:text=Advantage%20.NET%20Data%20Provider))

Use the following code to create a database connection:

```
var connection = System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Advantage.Data.Provider").CreateConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = "DATA SOURCE=C:\Ads\Databases\Example.add;ServerType=remote;USER ID=ADSSYS;PASSWORD=xxx;";
connection.Open();

var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandTask = "";
foreach (var param in Parameters) {
    var par = command.CreateParameter();
    par.ParameterName = "";
    par.Value = "";
    // par.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Boolean
    command.Parameters.Add(par);
}
```

Modify your `app.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <clear />
            <add name="Advantage Data Provider" invariant="Advantage.Data.Provider" description="" type="Advantage.Data.Provider.AdsFactory, Advantage.Data.Provider, Version=9.10.2.21, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e33137c86a38dc06" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Can you try that last part about the `app.config`?

If you did all this, and it still doesn't work, then it'll be an ADS version mismatch. Versions of:

- Advantage Database Server
- .NET Advantage Provider
- XML-tag that registers the database provider in your app.config

have to match.

Comment: You're probably right about the version mismatch, problem is that the client has 10.10 version installed, but .NET provider only goes to 8.10. No ideias left of what to do

Comment: Sadly not. We used Advantage ADS 8 at my previous job, so it's been some time... I only remember that you had to install a dataprovider as suggested. Other stuff was in the code, and I've skimmed our project, the stuff in this answer is 1/1 from the code

Comment: Thank you @Pieterjan for all your help! I'll see what I can do about it, and later will post my solution/mark yours as the right one

Comment: ADS .NET Data Providers are available for both 10.10 and 11.10, but it appears that SAP has made them inaccessible unless you have login credentials to their download area.  Contact your SAP sales rep and see if they can help you.   This may not pertain to your situation, but 11.10 has a bug that corrupts .DBF (cdx mode) headers.  I had to drop back to 8.10 because of this.  But 8.10 doesn't understand how to handle encrypted DBFs from an 11.10 server.